# Is this simple equivalence on Euler's identity true?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

Is the following equivalence true?

$$\cos(x\cdot a)+i\cdot \sin(x\cdot a)=e^{ix\cdot a}=(e^{ix})^a=(\cos(x)+i\cdot \sin(x))^{a}$$

why?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Power

Comment: Pretty straightforward. Thank you!

Comment: That proofwiki states something for real numbers.  Here, we have complex numbers...

Comment: @Botond Careful. The equation is not always true without further hypothesis about $x$ and $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Try $x = 2\pi$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$.  Then:

$$
\cos(x\cdot a)+i\cdot \sin(x\cdot a)=
\cos\pi+i\cdot\sin\pi = -1 + i\cdot 0 = -1
$$
and
$$
(\cos(x)+i\cdot \sin(x))^{a}=\big(\cos (2\pi) + i\sin(2\pi)\big)^{1/2}
=1^{1/2} = 1
$$
Now it is true that $-1$ is **a square root** of $1$.  But normally when we write $1^{1/2}$ we mean **the principal square root** of $1$, namely $1$.

Comment: That's right, but I didn't want to assume it true just because i get a couple results right.

Comment: The question now is: 
Given that the equivalence is true, is it still true to say 
$$\log((e^{ix})^{a})=a\cdot \log(e^{ix})$$
Thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, what you have done is actually proven De Moivre's theorem, assuming Euler's identity is correct. De Moivre's theorem states $(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$. So, if $e^{i\theta}=(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)$ (call this Equation $1$) is known, then following your method, $e^{in\theta}=(\cos \theta+i\sin \theta)^n$, and applying Equation $1$ again with $\theta$, replaced by $n\theta$ (to the left-hand side)  gives the theorem of De Moivre. At least when $n$ is a integer, we don't need to worry about what $(e^{i\theta})^n$ means.